# Why would you opt to fully qualify a package instead of importing it?

Tags: java, packages

In java, to print the date we could do either of the following:

**Fully qualified**

```
public class MyMain {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.out.println(new java.util.Date());

    }

}
```

**Using an import**

```
import java.util.*;

public class MyMain {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.out.println(new Date());

    }

}
```

What are the advantages and disadvantages to for each way?

For me, using an import seems tidier, as you can see at the top of your class, just what packages are being used.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When I need to use two different classes with the same name or the codebase I'm writing for often utilizes classes with the same names (which can happen if the classes are from different packages).

This isn't such a rare conflict to happen:

- java.util.Date
- java.sql.Date
- I can't tell you how many classes I've come across called "Document"

Keep in mind in your example that importing * means that you've increased the odds that you've imported a class with the same name as another class which was already imported.

Often if I'm only using a class in one place, I will not bother importing it but would rather explicitly say where it came from in the one place it's used.

Comment: +1 because I was working with two Documents (internal, and java XML based) earlier today :)